# System.DllNotFoundException: libodbc.so

Tags: mysql, mono, monodevelop

I'm a fresher in MonoDevelop tool. Kindly someone help to solve this issue.

Am getting this error while I am trying to connect to the MySql DB(however i can able to connect via Terminal). I am running mono on ubundu 14.4.

---

```
System.DllNotFoundException: libodbc.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.Odbc.libodbc:SQLAllocHandle (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandleType,intptr,intptr&)
  at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Please help

Regards

Karnaa Sattanathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install unixodbc package.

Comment: Thank you so much. That issue was resolved when i'm install "ODBC libraries for UNIX (development files)".

Best regards
Karnaa Sattanathan